# В чем заключается синтаксическая ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
if( Vars.Ragebot.Antiaim.Pitch == AA_PITCH_FAKE_HUYNA )
      flip + !flip;
flip2 = !flip2;
    if( flip )
        if (flip2)
        {
            G::SendPacket = false;
            viewangles.x -= 180.000000f;
            else
{
bSendThisPacket = true;
if (flip2)
G::UserCmd->viewangles.x += 131.000000f;
else if (!flip2)
G::UserCmd->viewangles.x -= 131.000000f;
}
}
```

Comment: `else` в очень странное место засунут. Расставьте отступы нормально, сразу станет видно.

Comment: if (Vars.Ragebot.Antiaim.Pitch == AA_PITCH_FAKE_HUYNA)
  flip = !flip;
 flip2 = !flip2;
 if (flip)
  if (flip2)
  {
   G::SendPacket = false;
   G::UserCmd->viewangles.x -= 180.000000f;
  }
  else
{
  G::SendPacket = true;
   if (flip2)
    G::UserCmd->viewangles.x += 131.000000f;
   else if (!flip2)
    G::UserCmd->viewangles.x -= 131.000000f;
  }

Comment: Спасиб, я прост не то немного сделал, сейчас просто 2 часа ночи

Comment: Вопрос не сформулирован даже мало-мальски осмысленным образом

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Vars.Ragebot.Antiaim.Pitch == AA_PITCH_FAKE_HUYNA) flip + !flip;
flip2 = !flip2;
if (flip) 
  if (flip2) {
    G::SendPacket = false;
    viewangles.x -= 180.000000f;
    else { // <------------- перед else не хватает }
      bSendThisPacket = true;
      if (flip2)
        G::UserCmd->viewangles.x += 131.000000f;
      else 
        if (!flip2) G::UserCmd->viewangles.x -= 131.000000f;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь выравниваниями и отступами.

Вот ваш же код, только с отступами. Вопросы есть или теперь сами видите?

```
if( Vars.Ragebot.Antiaim.Pitch == AA_PITCH_FAKE_HUYNA )
    flip + !flip;

flip2 = !flip2;

if( flip )
    if (flip2)
    {
        G::SendPacket = false;
        viewangles.x -= 180.000000f;
else
{
    bSendThisPacket = true;
    if (flip2)
        G::UserCmd->viewangles.x += 131.000000f;
    else if (!flip2)
        G::UserCmd->viewangles.x -= 131.000000f;
}
    }
```